# Highcharts - set xAxis range when using xAxis Categories?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How to update the highcharts xAxis range at runtime when using xAxis Categories ?

In the following JsFiddle, the desired result is when the user clicks 'All Months' they will see the full series data, and when the user clicks 'Two Months' , they will see only two months of data.

http://jsfiddle.net/looshi/4tuvC/453/

I've tried to use the xAxis functions `setExtremes`, and `setCategories`, but can't get it to work.

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]
    }]

});

$('#show-all-months').click(function() {
    //chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['Jan', 'Feb','Mar']);
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0,2);
});

$('#show-two-months').click(function() {
    //chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(['Jan', 'Feb']);
    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(0,1);
});
```

Comment: The docs for setExtremes() mentions, "will not allow a range lower than the minRange option, which by default is the range of five points". Given the values you are passing, have you set xAxis `minRange` attribute accordingly?

Comment: that looks like it works too : http://jsfiddle.net/looshi/4tuvC/465/  .   So, guess I could use an explicit min/max,  or simply set minRange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **Nathan** already pointed out in his comment - you are setting extremes that are below default [`minRange`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.minRange), so to fix this you could set mentioned option to e.g. 1.

```
...
xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
    minRange: 1
},
...
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4tuvC/468/